# Maven Deploy Plugin Replace the Existing SnapShot Jar in Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, deployment, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am using the Maven deploy plugin(3.0.0-M1/2.82)

to upload Snapshot jar to Jfrog Artifactory, but Plugin builds the SnapShot jar with the timeStamp and build Number(Default Behavior Of Maven Build with Timestamp while Remote Repository ) and says it uploading with name

example: project-extension-0.0.2-20200506.171928-1.jar but it uploads with SnapShot

name: project-extension-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar(0.0.2-SNAPSHOT  its Parent POM Version ) and replace it with the previous build Jar.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In your case: please edit your question to be more readable. Also, please provide details on what you want to achieve, your setup, and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how SNAPSHOTs work.

The file is uploaded with a timestamp name (and also saved as such internally). But usually just specify the version as `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT` and Maven resolves the latest timestamp for you.

Artifactory keeps the different versions, but can be configured to keep only the last n SNAPSHOTs.

Comment: Yes It Supposed to upload with timestamp, In IDE it showing the same that is correct, below is snippet. 


[INFO] Uploading: https://org.jfrog.io/artifactory/aps-maven-snapshots/com/org/cbc-extension/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/cbc-extension-0.0.2-20200506.174605-2.jar

when i see in JFrog :  cbc-extension-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar, and next build it overwrite the previous build, because file name will be the same everytime

I expect the file should be uploaded along with the timestamp.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Where exactly do you look in Artifactory?

Comment: Furthermore, why are you interested in the timestamps? They are usually not important because you always use the latest SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: To distinguish between different build either by build number or timestamp, in my case it replace with the previous build, because file name is always same i,e :  cbc-extension-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar 

I am looking into GUI of Jfrog location which i have given into <distributionManagement> Tag URL

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is just in the GUI, in which Artifactory hides the timestamps. But let me stress that only in special circumstances, you ever need these timestamps.  if you want to address different versions, just built release versions.